# How to create RDFS based on RDF/XML file?

Tags: c#, rdf, rdfs, dotnetrdf, rdf-xml

For my project, I need to get the RDFS from CIM RDF/XML (IEC 61970). .NET Framework does not have standard tools for working with RDF. Please help me solve my problem.

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "get the RDFS from CIM RDF/XML"?

Comment: `RDF/XML` is a serialization format for `RDF`, thus, the dataset already contains `RDF` and/or `RDFS` data...

Comment: I thought there were utilities like xsd.exe for getting RDFS

Comment: Perhaps you just need this file: http://www.langdale.com.au/CIMXML/rdf_and_html_10_010825c.zip From here: http://www.langdale.com.au/CIMXML/

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I need. The standard IEC 61970 has changed a lot, this scheme is quite old and is no longer relevant. Perhaps I was wrong and I do not need any RDF scheme at all. I wanted to make a validation mechanism for CIM CML/RDF files. If you know, can you explain how I should do the validation mechanism?

Comment: Well, SHACL, ShEx or something else... Perhaps you could be interested in [RDFUnit](https://github.com/AKSW/RDFUnit/blob/master/README.md#supported-schemas).

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be with C#?. I use JAVA + JENA to process the CIM/XML files to extract it data. (It works fine with the CIM 16 schema version "http://iec.ch/TC57/2013/CIM-schema-cim16#").
Maybe you can create the JAVA code and call it from C# or use any native .NET library for parsing XML. In this post [How match JAXB elements in CIM/RDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429483/how-match-jaxb-elements-in-cim-rdf) seems they are working with JAXB.