# Create RDF model with typed classes and rdf:id

Tags: java, xml, rdf, jena

I got to this question: [How match JAXB elements in CIM/RDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429483/how-match-jaxb-elements-in-cim-rdf) looking for ways to create CIM/XML files with the RDF.
Trough the question I learned how to get a RDF file in this format

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="idObject2">
    <myns:Object2.Property rdf:resource="#idAnotherObject"/>
    <cim:IdentifiedObject.aliasName>CP01</cim:IdentifiedObject.aliasName>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="idObject1">
    <myns:GeneralObject.Object2 rdf:resource="#idObject2"/><cim:IdentifiedObject.aliasName>GT01</cim:IdentifiedObject.aliasName>
</rdf:Description>
```

The CIM standard adds a # within the id on the rdf:resource so we don't  get a more hierarchical format like this

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="idObject1">
    <myns:GeneralObject.Object2>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="idObject2">
        <iso:Object2.Property rdf:resource="#idAnotherObject"/>
        <cim:IdentifiedObject.aliasName>CP01</cim:IdentifiedObject.aliasName>
      </rdf:Description>
    </myns:GeneralObject.Object2>
    <cim:IdentifiedObject.aliasName>GT01</cim:IdentifiedObject.aliasName>
  </rdf:Description>
```

RDF (or just JENA, I don't know exactly) when finds the same id, it nested the classes. Then, to process the data, we need to somehow parse the rdf:resource string to remove the #

So, with this context, my questions are...

1) How do I write the `rdf:id` instead of the `rdf:about`

2) How do I substitute the `rdf:Descritpion` with my own class name, e.g. `myns:Object1`

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you parse the RDF by using Jena and then create the XML as you want?

Comment: I don't know, that I why I am asking. I am creating the RDF from a set of JAVA Classes (manually right now, because I am learning how to do it) Create the XML... by means of DOM or JAXB, you mean? I was expecting to manipulate the RDF using JENA API. There should be some method in JENA to handle if this no?

Comment: RDF/XML serialization is something technical -you'd probably have to dig into the internals of Jena (or RIOT). Please ask this question on the **Jena mailing list**, the developers know better what to do. From a semantical point of view, serialization stuff doesn't matter for most people as long as the RDF triples are encoded correctly.

Comment: Thanks @AKSW I will use the Jena mailing list! Meanwhile, I leave the question here, let's hope someone else has face this issue before!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question 2, I have to create the Resource in this way:

```
    Resource object1 = model.createResource(idObject1, 
            model.createResource(Basics.getURI()+ Object1.class.getSimpleName()))
```

so in this way, the output is something like this:

```
    <myns:Object1 rdf:about="idObject1">
        <myns:GeneralObject.Object2 rdf:resource="#idObject2"/>
        <cim:IdentifiedObject.aliasName>GT01</cim:IdentifiedObject.aliasName>
    </myns:Object1>
```